# My array isn't holding the values I give it, is there any fix? Python

Tags: python, arrays, import

So basically I'm trying to script a game (Card-Jitsu), but uh my array isn't actually storing the values I give it. I have 2 files currently (I'm trying to make a project involving import). Here is the code that generates a random number which I use to pick a card from my cards array:

```
n = 0
helper = 0
n2 = 0
helper2 = 0

cards = ["Fire 1", "Fire 2", "Fire 3", "Water 1", "Water 2", "Water 3", "Thunder 1", "Thunder 2", "Thunder 3"]

while n < 4:
    import random
    cardNum = random.randint(0, 8)

    userDeck = ["", "", "", ""]
    userDeck[helper] = cards[cardNum]
    n = n + 1
    helper = helper + 1

while n2 < 4:
    import random
    cardNum = random.randint(0, 8)

    compDeck = ["", "", "", ""]
    compDeck[helper2] = cards[cardNum]
    n2 = n2 + 1
    helper2 = helper2 + 1
```

And this is the other code in which I have all the other stuff:

```
if start == "PLAY": #Still in progress!
    print("This game is a luck based game, it's basically a copy of Rock-Paper-Scissors. Fire > Thunder, Thunder > Water, Water > Fire. Let's play now!")
    print("Your deck contains", userDeck[0], userDeck[1], userDeck[2], userDeck[3])
```

But when I run the file in the terminal this is what I get:

```
Welcome to Card Game! Type PLAY to continue!
PLAY
This game is a luck based game, it's basically a copy of Rock-Paper-Scissors. Fire > Thunder, Thunder > Water, Water > Fire. Let's play now!
Your deck contains    Thunder 1
```

Someone, please tell me how to fix this in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move `compDeck` and `userDeck` outside of the loops.  Otherwise you write over them with each iteration of the loop.

```
userDeck = ["", "", "", ""]
while n < 4:
    import random
    cardNum = random.randint(0, 8)
    userDeck[helper] = cards[cardNum]
    n = n + 1
    helper = helper + 1
```

Also try checking out this function to save you some time:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample